# Can we use Angular Templateurl to direct toMVC .cshtml views

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, razor, localhost

Can we use Templateurl to direct to .cshtml views.

`@Component({
  selector: 'sq-button',
  templateUrl: '../../Views/Component/Button',
  styleUrls: ['button.component.css']
})`

The above code is loading the views in iis express, But when I change the project properties to local iis, I get the following errors.

`1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2. Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load http://localhost/Views/Component/Button ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load http://localhost/Views/Component/Button`

Do I have to make any changes after changing the project to local iis?

Comment: http://localhost/Views/Component/Button , Is this correct url ?

Comment: Yes! the url is correct. The same url works when i run it in IIS express. But not when I change it to local IIS @vishalsharma

Comment: `404 (Not Found)` Indicates resource deosnt exists , you might have some issue with hosting only , check Local IIS Manager,

Comment: `templateUrl: '../../Views/Component/Button',` you need to change this .. 

try '/directory/views/component/button' not .././